# Roundup function in xslt1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

> I need to roundup the number to 2 decimals in xslt.
>
> ```
> 1.231>>1.24
>
> 1.238>>1.24
>     
>
> Do we have any function defined?
> ```

Comment: do you mean like `round(...)` and `format-number(...)` ? - you could combine them like:  `format-number(round(1.231), '0.00')`

Comment: @blurfus I believe you are missing the UP requirement. Not to mention that `round()`rounds to the nearest integer - so the result in your suggested solution would be `1.00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we have any function defined?

The [ceiling()](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-ceiling) function rounds up to the nearest integer, so do:

```
ceiling($n * 100) div 100
```